# Firefox Geolocation PERMISSION_DENIED (using self signed HTTPS certificate)

Tags: ssl, firefox, https, geolocation

I get **PERMISSION_DENIED** for `geolocation` even when I answer **"Allow"** geolocation on popup.

Page Info for `localhost:xxxx` - **"Access Your Location"** shows **Allow radio button as marked**!

I am using a self-signed certificate on localhost and had added an exception for `localhost:xxxx`, so the site otherwise (obviously) works fine.

Is self signed certificate interfering with geolocation? 
 
(Firefox version 54.0 (Ubuntu)) 
(`geo.enabled` is `true` in about:config)

Answer (score 0):

This is what eventually worked - [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1104359)
(instead of Google's geo-location services, Mozilla's geo-location services were required)